# undefined reference to errors when compiling c files?

Tags: gcc, python3

Here is the question that encountered during the compiling process. The main purpose is to compile a c file that is generated from python using cython. Shall I still need to include other link libraries or any suggested way to compile well ?

```
paultsai@paultsai-virtual-machine:~/cython/ex2$ gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.5/ -lpython3.5 -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/  -o prime_numbers_2 prime_numbers_2.c


 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in
 function _start: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to「main」
 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr:
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference
 to「PyObject_GetAttr」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __pyx_pf_15prime_numbers_2_is_prime: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to「PyTuple_New」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x24b):
 undefined reference to「PyList_Type」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x267):
 undefined reference to「PyTuple_Type」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x2c4):
 undefined reference to「PyObject_GetIter」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x3db): undefined reference to「PyList_Type」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x4d7): undefined reference
 to「PyErr_Occurred」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x4f3): undefined
 reference to「PyExc_StopIteration」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x50c):
 undefined reference to「PyExc_StopIteration」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference
 to「PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x530):
 undefined reference to「PyErr_Clear」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x604):
 undefined reference to「PyNumber_Remainder」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x7f6): undefined reference
 to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x80b): undefined
 reference to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x8ab):
 undefined reference to「_Py_TrueStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x8c0): undefined reference
 to「_Py_TrueStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x969): undefined
 reference to「_Py_NoneStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x970):
 undefined reference to「_Py_NoneStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x97b): undefined reference
 to「_Py_NoneStruct」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __Pyx_InitCachedConstants: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xb62): undefined reference to「PyTuple_Pack」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xc17): undefined
 reference to「PyCode_New」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __Pyx_InitGlobals: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xcac): undefined reference to「PyLong_FromLong」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xcf6):
 undefined reference to「PyLong_FromLong」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 PyInit_prime_numbers_2: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xd8e): undefined
 reference to「PyTuple_New」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xde0): undefined
 reference to「PyBytes_FromStringAndSize」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xe32): undefined reference
 to「PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xe84):
 undefined reference to「PyModule_Create2」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xed6): undefined reference
 to「PyModule_GetDict」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xf34): undefined
 reference to「PyImport_AddModule」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0xf92):
 undefined reference to「PyObject_SetAttrString」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1012): undefined reference
 to「PyObject_SetAttrString」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1042): undefined
 reference to「PyImport_GetModuleDict」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x108e):
 undefined reference to「PyDict_GetItemString」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x10ab): undefined reference
 to「PyDict_SetItemString」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1156): undefined
 reference to「PyCFunction_NewEx」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x11ae):
 undefined reference to「PyDict_SetItem」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1221): undefined reference to「PyDict_New」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1279): undefined reference
 to「PyDict_SetItem」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x13ba): undefined
 reference to「PyErr_Occurred」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x13c6):
 undefined reference to「PyExc_ImportError」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x13d3): undefined reference
 to「PyErr_SetString」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function __Pyx_GetBuiltinName:
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1419): undefined reference
 to「PyExc_NameError」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x142f): undefined
 reference to「PyErr_Format」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __Pyx_PyObject_Call: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1483): undefined reference to「PyObject_Call」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x148d):
 undefined reference to「PyThreadState_Get」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x149f): undefined reference
 to「_Py_CheckRecursionLimit」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x14b6):
 undefined reference to「_Py_CheckRecursiveCall」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x14eb): undefined reference
 to「PyThreadState_Get」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x14fd): undefined
 reference to「_Py_CheckRecursionLimit」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x150a): undefined reference
 to「_Py_CheckRecursionLimit」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1515):
 undefined reference to「_Py_CheckRecursionLimit」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1529): undefined reference
 to「PyThreadState_Get」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1542): undefined
 reference to「PyErr_Occurred」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1557):
 undefined reference to「PyExc_SystemError」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1564): undefined reference
 to「PyErr_SetString」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function __Pyx_PyInt_EqObjC:
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1590): undefined reference
 to「_Py_TrueStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x159f): undefined
 reference to「_Py_TrueStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x15b2):
 undefined reference to「PyLong_Type」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x169d):
 undefined reference to「_Py_FalseStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x16ac): undefined reference
 to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x16c0): undefined
 reference to「_Py_TrueStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x16cf):
 undefined reference to「_Py_TrueStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x16d9): undefined reference
 to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x16e8): undefined
 reference to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x16fb):
 undefined reference to「PyFloat_Type」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1730):
 undefined reference to「_Py_TrueStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x173f): undefined reference
 to「_Py_TrueStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1746): undefined
 reference to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1755):
 undefined reference to「_Py_FalseStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x176f): undefined reference
 to「PyObject_RichCompare」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __pyx_insert_code_object: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x196a): undefined reference to「PyMem_Malloc」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1ad0): undefined
 reference to「PyMem_Realloc」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1be5): undefined reference to「PyUnicode_FromString」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1c1a): undefined reference
 to「PyUnicode_FromFormat」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1c2c): undefined
 reference to「PyUnicode_FromString」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1ca2):
 undefined reference to「PyCode_New」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __Pyx_AddTraceback: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1e58): undefined reference to「PyThreadState_Get」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1e6f):
 undefined reference to「PyFrame_New」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1e90):
 undefined reference to「PyTraceBack_Here」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function
 __Pyx_check_binary_version: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1f75): undefined reference to「PyOS_snprintf」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1f7a): undefined reference
 to「Py_GetVersion」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1f9e): undefined
 reference to「PyOS_snprintf」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x1ffa):
 undefined reference to「PyOS_snprintf」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x2013): undefined reference to「PyErr_WarnEx」
 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in function __Pyx_InitStrings:
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x207f): undefined reference
 to「PyUnicode_InternFromString」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x20c4):
 undefined reference to「PyUnicode_Decode」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x20ef): undefined reference
 to「PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x211a):
 undefined reference to「PyBytes_FromStringAndSize」 /tmp/ccgBhADM.o: in
 function __Pyx_PyObject_IsTrue: prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x2168):
 undefined reference to「_Py_TrueStruct」
 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x2179): undefined reference
 to「_Py_FalseStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x218c): undefined
 reference to「_Py_NoneStruct」 prime_numbers_2.c:(.text+0x21a9):
 undefined reference to「PyObject_IsTrue」 collect2: error: ld returned 1
 exit status paultsai@paultsai-virtual-machine:~/cython/ex2$
```

Comment: Check your link order - see for example [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/4440445)

Comment: after modifying the orders of link library and recompile, there still
shows one undefined reference to main as shown below:
there seems that Shall I need to define by my own self ? 
in xxx.c file ? `paultsai@paultsai-virtual-machine:~/cython/ex2$ 
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.5 \ 
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/ \ 
prime_numbers_2.c -lpython3.5 -o prime_numbers_2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function _start:
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to「main」
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Is  this problem related to the version of Python ? python2.7 and python3.5 ??

Comment: Usually, `undefined reference to main` means exactly what it says: programs need a `main` function as their entry point - does your `prime_numbers_2.c` have one? BTW please don't post big chunks of code in comments - you can [edit] your question instead.

Comment: The prime_numbers_2.c is from prime_numbers_2.pyx, and it only define function, no main . main is defined by another script.py. So, shall I need to compile the script.py into script.c file and then replace prime_numbers_2.c with script.c in the above command ?

Comment: The result is same "undefined reference to main" after replacing prime_numbers_2.c with the script.c and recompiled  Its really strange !!

Comment: You can *compile* `.c` files to `.o` files without a `main()`, but you won't be able to link them into an executable.  Let's take a step back - what *exactly* are you trying to do here? If you are trying to create a `cython` module, you probably shouldn't be using `gcc` directly.

Comment: I want to test the execution time of different kinds of coding style, such as python style and compiled cython style. The main test block is in prime_numbers_2.pyx. So I wrote a different style of code in prime_numbers_2 and tried to cythonize my code to have better execution performance. So, what is your suggested way to test cython modules peformance without gcc ?